# Sql filtering id's

Tags: sql

I want to create a sql query that lets me make a top 5 of the most used ids in my table.
My table has these columns:

```
reservationid
costumerid
roomid
hotelid
```

I'm trying to get a top 5 of the most used hotel ids.

I thought I had to use the count function but that doesn't seem to work. It just counts all the hotelids and doesn't see the difference between the id's

```
select count(hotelid) from reservation;
```

Can someone help me push me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(`hotelid`) AS `freq`, `hotelid` 
        FROM `reservation` 
    GROUP BY `hotelid` 
    ORDER BY `freq` DESC LIMIT 5 ;
```

Comment: `COUNT(*)` would give the same reuslt.

Comment: if it works, please mark the question as answered so that others know.

Comment: marked it, had to wait 10 minutes! you were to fast for the system it seems !